# How to return JSON in Flask server built with Haxe

Tags: python, flask, haxe

I'm trying to build a Flask server using Haxe, and I'm stumped on how to return a JSON. I got an example up and running using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nadako/62ecfba4b6faf14a6c67) that has `Main.index()` return a String, but when I try to return a String from `haxe.Json.stringify()` I get an error when I try to run the output Python.

```
import haxe.Constraints.Function;

@:pythonImport("flask", "Flask")
extern class Flask {
    function new(module:String);
    function route<T:Function>(path:String):T->T;
    function run():Void;
}

class Main {
    static function main() {
        var app = new Flask(untyped __name__);
        app.route("/")(index);
        app.run();
    }

    static function index() {
        return haxe.Json.stringify({msg:"hello"});
    }
}
```

Python error:

```
$ python main.py
  File "main.py", line 69
    return haxe_format_JsonPrinter.print(_hx_AnonObject({'msg': "hello"}),None,None)
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using Python 3? Haxe's python target only supports Python 3 if I'm not mistaken. (And I'm guessing that you would get the above error in Python 2, because in Python 2 "print" was a statement / keyword and probably couldn't be used as a function name)

Comment: If you are using Python 3 then sorry I'm not sure :)

Comment: @JasonO'Neil that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Sweet, I guess i should post that as an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be well documented but Haxe's python target only supports Python 3. See https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/issues/4195

In this case, "print" was a keyword in Python 2, and the Haxe generated code is trying to generate a function named "print", hence the error.

Try:

```
python3 main.py
```

to have it run correctly.